# Using abstract classes and accessing them as one entity, OOP Design?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm unsure of the exact way to implement my classes.

Say i have Baseball and Basketball classes that have characteristics different from eachother and both extend sports..

My example, i have:

```
public abstract class Sports
{
    public abstract getSport();
    public abstract getCoach();
    public abstract getTeamSize() 
    {
        System.out.println("The size of the team is xxx.");
    }
}

public class Baseball extends Sports
{
    public List<Baseballs> getBaseballs()
    {
        // Get list of another object baseballs.
    }
    // Implementation of abstract methods.
}

public class Basketball extends Sports
{
    public List<Basketballs> getBasketballs()
    {
        // Get list of another object basketballs.
    }
    // Implementation of abstract methods.
}
```

Say i want a `List<Sports> sports` that contains all the sports defined. But as im accessing these lists i want to print the lists of basketballs and baseballs depending on what it is. Would i need to type cast these to figure out which method to call? Is this bad design?

Another thought i had was, but it seems to be a little manual work and not correct lol.

```
public class Sports
{
    String sportType = "[Sport]";
    List<Basketball> basketballs;
    List<Baseball> baseballs;
    public getTeamSize() 
    {
        System.out.println("The size of the team is 10.");
    }
    public List<Basketball> getBasketballs 
    {
        return this.basketballs;
    }
    public List<Baseball> getBaseballs
    {
        return this.baseballs;
    }
}
```

So when iterating over this object somewhere, i can do

```
switch (type) {
case "Baseball":
    // Iterate and print baseball list.
case "Basketball":
    // Iterate and print basketball list.
}
```

and for this case say Baseball and Basketball are so far different from eachother, they have 0 similar characteristics.

But then i would have an unused declaration for Baseball and same for Basketball.

Comment: That's one option, or you could have a "Balls" (I am tempted to say "IBalls" but stopped using that notation over a decade ago) interface and just check for that interface. If present, you could call `getBalls` which returns a collection of `Ball`, and have another class/class hierarchy for balls.

Comment: To expand on the above, you can define a generic parameter `<B extends Ball>` and have `getBalls()` return `List<B>` and subclass it as `Basketball extends Sports<Basketballs>`.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks dave for the reply, im diving more into this format as it may suite my needs.  The Ball heirarchy might work, just a little extra engineering that i may have to do, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got an operation you want to be able to perform on any `Sports` object, regardless of its actual type. To do that, you want to define it in the base class (probably `abstract`), and then include relevant implementations in the child classes.

For instance, you should give `Sports` a method: `protected abstract void printBalls()`

And then implement it appropriately in each subclass. For instance in `Baseball` you could have:

```
@Override
protected abstract void printBalls() {
  for(Baseball baseball: this.getBaseballs()) {
    System.out.println(baseball);
  }
}
```

Comment: How would i handle return types, for these override methods in the sub classes of Sports. If it was just printing i think that would be fine, but was about retrieving? If one returns List<Basketball> vs <Baseball> , i still would need some type of control statement that handles which type to retrieve?

Comment: In that case, the return type would be something like `List<? extends Sports>`. If you can't express the return type this way, you should reconsider whether this is really something that it makes sense to iterate over without knowing what type of `Sports` you are actually working with a priori.

Comment: Yeah i saw using `List<? extends Sports>` which may work for my case. I was going to maybe use the `SportType` field to know which sport im working with and which type of list to get. I will definitely reconsider my options though and other ways to go about it. Thank you !!

Comment: Needing to check for the actual type of a subclass (whether by checking the type itself or by checking a static flag) is generally poor design. For example, if you want to add another subclass, you've now got to make change in two places--first, in the new class you're creating; and second, in the superclass method that handles different subclasses differently.

Comment: I agree on the terrible design on the static flag, ignoring that route. you and the others definitely gave me a better path to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, you need same method for different type of lists. Casting is not always a good idea, what you need is interface. This is like universal "class" with your methods. Code for interfaces is almost same and you can implement in your classes what you want and interface will chose which method to call depends on type.The methods in interface and in classes must be same and classes must implement interface.

Comment: I agree on the type casting. How would i handle return types, for these override methods in the sub classes of Sports. If one returns List<Basketball> vs <Baseball> , i still would need some type of control statement that handles which type to retrieve?

Comment: If you say List<Sports> (but i think Sports cant be abstract) as return type of your methods, when you insert in list a class that extends Sports, you call "universal" method, different type will call different method and return type will be same (List<Sports>) and you can continue working with it.This is call hiding behind classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code is much better although still lack of bit of something, here is the code I am talking about:

```
    public class Sports
    {
        String sportType = "[Sport]";
        List<Basketball> basketballs;
        List<Baseball> baseballs;
        public getTeamSize() 
        {
            System.out.println("The size of the team is 10.");
        }
        public List<Basketball> getBasketballs 
        {
            return this.basketballs;
        }
        public List<Baseball> getBaseballs
        {
            return this.baseballs;
        }
    }
```

Now notice how sports does not do really anything other then containing the 2 lists that contain the classes "basketball" and "baseball" reppresenting the teams.

A better way would be to say, well, basketball and baseball are both sports, and I am trying to represent sport teams (I don't really know how inclusive you want the sports to be, eg: are the sports classified by a particular attribute? Eg: these sports involve using a ball or having a team of 5 etc... [Sorry I am not big in sports]), these sport teams have attributes thus:

```
public abstract class Sports {

    private static List<Sports> teams = new ArrayList<>();
    private int size;
    private String teamName;



    public Sports(String teamName) {

        this.teamName = teamName;
        teams.add(this);

    }

    public Sports(String teamName, int size) {
        this.size = 0;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        teams.add(this);
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void printSports() {

        Iterator<Sports> it = teams.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()) {

            Sports tmp = it.next();

            if(tmp instanceof Basketball) {
                System.out.println(tmp.getTeamName());
            }else if(tmp instanceof Baseball) {
                System.out.println("Something else");
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract int getTeamSize();
    public abstract void setTeamSize(int sizeOfTeam);

}
```

Basketball class:

```
public class Basketball extends Sports {

    private int sizeOfTeam;

    public Basketball(String teamName) {
        super(teamName, 10);
        //Defaults 10 players
    }

    @Override
    public int getTeamSize() {
        return sizeOfTeam;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTeamSize(int sizeOfTeam) {
        this.sizeOfTeam = sizeOfTeam;
    }
}
```

Baseball class:

```
public class Baseball extends Sports {

    private int sizeOfTeam;

    public Baseball() {
        super("team");
    }

    @Override
    public int getTeamSize() {
        return sizeOfTeam;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTeamSize(int sizeOfTeam) {
        this.sizeOfTeam = sizeOfTeam;
    }
}
```

I oversimplified it, although this is a much betterway you basically can define any attribute how you want and automatically add it to a list that will always be there until the end of the program. You can choose to make the object in another class (look below I used the driver), or simply add stuff to the list directly in the Sports class itself like making as many sports objects you want however you want and self contained them. For baseball and basketball, I gave you two examples of classes that have been oversimplified, but basically play the game of the abstract class, allowing you to be flexible in how you define them, either by hard coding or not.

Hope it helps.

Driver:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Sports sports = new Basketball("Team1");
        sports = new Baseball();

        sports.printSports();

    }
}
```

Comment: This example requires the caller to new up all possible sports. In which case you already have a list of all possible sports. Or not? And the printSports() should probably be static as it does not involve any logic concerning a specific instance of Sport. This will reveal the problem that your printSports() method is dependent on x invocations of the Sports constructor in order to function properly.

Comment: Well it I think he knows all sports, I did assume since he has them listed. But yeah if you don't know all sports don't use this that is quite obvious. Yes the print sports method can be static.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 'formal' pattern for that switch statement I suppose you could write a visitor. I'm not a huge fan of this pattern but it seems applicable to your problem.

You can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

The example on the wiki page also solves a printing problem similar to yours.

Here is the pattern translated into your domain language:

```
public interface ISport
{
    void Accept(ISportsVisitor visitor);
}

public interface ISportsVisitor 
{
    void Visit(Basketball basketball);
    void Visit(Baseball baseball);
}

public class Baseball : Sport, ISport
{
    // ...
    public void Accept(ISportsVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
    //...
}

public class SportsPrinter : ISportsVisitor
{
    public void Visit(Basketball basketball)
    {
        // Print basketballs
    }

    public void Visit(Baseball baseball)
    {
        // Print baseballs
    }
}
```

Then in your main app:

```
var sportsPrinter = new SportsPrinter();

foreach(var sport in sports)
{
    sport.Accept(sportsPrinter);
}
```

This is quite a weird pattern to get used to and it does not express intent that well. I suppose you could deviate from the standard terminology to try and improve it. However, after you have this pattern in place, you can add other functionality to your domain models without touching them.

If you need return types then you can alter the visitor interface to be so. Let's say that some of your sports can have team captains and other not (for example tennis) and you need a list of captains for all sports. You could have an interface like this:

```
public interface IAnotherSportsVisitor
{
    Person Accept(Baseball basball);
    // And an accept method for the relevant sports
}

public class CaptainCollectionVisitor : IAnotherSportsVisitor
{
    public Person Visit(Baseball baseball)
    {
        return baseball.GetCaptain();
    }

    public Person Visit(Tennis tennis)
    {
        return null; // or maybe return GetTeamManager()? 
    }
}

public class Baseball : ISport
{
    //...
    public Person Accept(IAnotherSportsVisitor visitor)
    {
        return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
    //...
}

public class Tennis: ISport
{
    //...
    public Person Accept(IAnotherSportsVisitor visitor)
    {
        return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
    //...
}
```

And in your main application:

```
var captains = sports.Select(x => x.Accept(captainCollectionVisitor)).Where(x => x!= null);
```